# Android Studio - SQL Syntax Error

Tags: java, android, sql

Creating my first App in Android Studio. Creating a database to store values of customers.

This is the error I'm getting;

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "Details": syntax error
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Surname=Cliff Contact Details=James@gmail.com  Address=111 First Name=James
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Details": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Customer_Table(Surname,Contact Details,Address,First Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                  #################################################################
                  Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                    (near "Details": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Customer_Table(Surname,Contact Details,Address,First Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?))
                  #################################################################
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1005)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:570)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1771)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1643)
                      at com.example.user.plannerv2.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:43)
                      at com.example.user.plannerv2.Customer$1.onClick(Customer.java:39)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Not 100% sure where the error is coming from, Just starting to learn SQL.

This is my database.java class

```
    package com.example.user.plannerv2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by user on 30/03/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Customer.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Customer_Table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "First Name";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Surname";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Address";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Contact Details";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRST TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, CONTACT TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String first, String surname, String address, String contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,first);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,address);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,contact);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Any help would be great :) Thanks.

Comment: please learn sql basics: table names with spaces

Comment: One of the basic things is : don't query non-existing columns . "Contact Details" and "First Name" don't exist in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column names for `COL_2` and `COL_5` are invalid. You need to either remove the spaces or surround the column name with square brackets. Since the brackets are considered bad practice, I recommend you change `COL_2` and `COL_5` as follows:

```
public static final String COL_2 = "First_Name";
public static final String COL_5 = "Contact_Details";
```

Comment: `Column names cannot contain spaces.` This is not strictly true. You actually **can** have spaces in column names: `public static final String COL_2 = "[First Name]";
public static final String COL_5 = "[Contact Details]";`.

Comment: Well TIL. Thanks for letting me know. Point still stands that the columns are invalid in their current form.

Comment: And, agreed, putting spaces in column names (as well as in any other database object other than raw data) is really a bad practice.